# How to add formatters others than json for Asp core OData?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to know how to enable the support for xml and other formats for asp core odata endpoints. Currently only supported format using default configuration is json.

For this test I have built a webapi core odata service at `http://localhost:59191/odata/Employee`.

But `http://localhost:59191/odata/Employee?$format=xml`, `http://localhost:59191/odata/Employee?$format=atom` both end up providing json.

Then I tried with fiddler using Accept header for `application/xml` and atom format which still doesn't provide xml formatting.

*In startup.cs I have configured it in following way*

1) At `ConfigureServices()`,

```
services.AddOData();
```

2) At `Configure()`

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetModel());

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


        });
```

where GetModel is,

```
   private static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employee").EntityType.HasKey(x=>x.Id);

        builder.EntityType<Employee>().Filter().Count().Select();
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Thanks for taking your time to contribute.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this one?